# createSQLQuery in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have the following code:

```
String SQL_QUERY ="Select abstractDesc from article";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(SQL_QUERY);
Object [] amount = (Object []) query.uniqueResult(); 
out.println("mean amount: " + amount[0]);
```

but I get the following error:

> Hibernate: Select abstractDesc from article
>       query did not return a unique result: 10

How can I solve this to have the query executed and print the result properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `uniqueResult()`, you are telling Hibernate that you are expecting only a single value.

Check your database or replace `uniqueResult()` with `[list()]`[1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29) to see what you get back.